# A* algorithm sorting the spaces so I can get the shortest and add to the openlist, closedlist which I have not yet created

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Here is the revised code, the other classes don't matter I hope. If you need the other classes, tell me and I'll add it. When I run this I get the naming error when I try to retrieve the spaces that are possible to move in.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Space> openlist = new ArrayList<Space>();
        int g = 0;
        Bot Dave = new Bot("Dave");

        Goal goal = new Goal();

        Obstacle first = new Obstacle("First");
        int numofobst = 1;
        Space right = new Space(Dave.getX()+1, Dave.getY());
        Space left = new Space(Dave.getX()-1, Dave.getY());
        Space up = new Space(Dave.getX(), Dave.getY()+1);
        Space down = new Space(Dave.getX(), Dave.getY()-1);

        int openpossible= 0;
        //now its creating an array of each space and getting the fs of each one. 

        /*time to check which spaces are possible for the bot to move. if they are possible add the space to a possible array list. 
         * then we check to see which f is smaller by addign a min value. 
         * we then sort it and get the first space.
         * we move to that space.
         */

        if (Dave.checkob(first, right, numofobst) == right){
        openlist.add(right);
        }
        if (Dave.checkob(first, left, numofobst) == left){
            openlist.add(left);
            }
        if (Dave.checkob(first, up, numofobst) == up){
            openlist.add(up);}
        if (Dave.checkob(first, down, numofobst) == down){
            openlist.add(down);}
        for (int i = 0; i < openlist.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Space available is" + openlist.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Space available is" + openlist);


    }
```

Comment: Ugh. "see if you can lead me in the right direction"? No. Lead yourself, and [learn how to ask a good question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Who knows -- by the time you've done the work you must do to ask a good question, you might even know the answer.

Comment: uh, im a beginner, and im not an expert, btw ive looked at how a* works, but implementing that into a language i yet have a fulll grasp at is not possible for me at this moment.

Comment: And i do know how to ask a good question. Im simply trying to see how someone would do it so can learn from it. I know somehwat how to do it in smallbasic which i excel at but it seems smallbasic is limited to what i am trying to do.

Comment: so this is graph A* I presume you should add a tag (people are forgetting A* is used also for 2D grid maps wich is quite a bit different ...)

Answer (score 0):

You're code is missing a lot of things (mostly everything).

First try to implement a simple [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Do the one in O(V^2), then upgrade it to O(ElogV). It's a bit slower than A* but a lot simpler to understand. Once you get it you can upgrade it to A* by changing a few lines of code.

Comment: I actually, have now added a couple more lines of code. I added the equaltion f=g+h. and if i recall i added 1 other one as well.  i do not have the code with me at the moment but ill add another answer with it. I also wont be working with graphics. just outputs.  i will try to learn about dijkstra as well.

Comment: I am using the arraylist function and i have it working, but the naming convetion they are using is like some hexidecimal(What the heck) i when through each space and check to see if it is possible to move to that space. but when i print it out, i get Space@403b3b81. its the same for eachc other space but with a different arrangement. Why is that happening?